# Order by highest number of records in a field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I'd like to order contents of a table from MySQL database that looks like below.

```
name,h1,h2
a,f1,3
a,g3,5
a,h3,4
b,g3,4
c,h5,2
c,j12,6
```

I'd like to get the lengths for each element in name column i.e, length of 'a' would be 3 (since it has three rows of data associated with it) and **get data of the top 2 elements** (here it'd include 3 rows for a's and 2 for c's since they have the highest length in descending order). So the required output would look something like below

```
name,h1,h2
a,f1,3
a,g3,5
a,h3,4
c,h5,2
c,j12,6
```

How can this be achieved in MySQL?

Comment: "length of 'a' would be 2 (since it has three rows of data associated with it)" How's the length of 2 related to three?

Comment: I find it difficult to understand your examples when your output is missing a record from the original and all we're talking about is ordering.

Comment: I'm sorry that was a mistake. I edited later to add an extra row to a.@dasblinkenlight

Comment: @paqogomez I need to order and select the top records (which'd exclude rows of 'b' then.) I hope I make sense.

Comment: Ok, then what defines the "top records"?

Comment: @paqogomez as I mentioned in the question, top records (I need top two records) would include "all" the rows associated with 'a' and 'c' since they have the highest length.

Comment: @abn glad that worked for you! Sorry for the initial confusion on the spec.

Comment: @abn, FWIW, I was just reading your previous questions.  You might change the word 'length' to 'number of rows'.  Length in sql generally refers to how long the string of characters in a field is.  eg. `len('asdf')` would be 4 characters in length.

Comment: @paqogomez Sure. Thank you. I'm new to MySQL, I used to do all this stuff in R, where length gives the number of rows/columns. I will change it. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65236/discussion-between-abn-and-paqogomez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining to a count of the top two records should give you your results.

```
select
  t.*
from
  table1 t
  inner join (select 
                name, 
                count(*) as cnt 
              from table1 
              group by name
              order by count(*) desc
              limit 2) as c on t.name = c.name
order by c.cnt desc
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd293/1)

Comment: @abn note that i added the desc on the final order by and added a working fiddle example.